# Warm-Up Script not writing to log file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, logging

I have been working on implementing the warm-up script from [Ingo Karstein Warm-Up Script](http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/08/03/sharepoint-warm-up-now-with-timeout/)

The script runs without any issues, but the log file (.txt) is not being generated as expected. I have the scripts in a directory c:\Tools\Scripts

```
# SharePoint Warmup Script
# by Ingo Karstein
# 2011/01/26
# 2011/08/02

 #<---- Improvement starts here
#region MyWebClient
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Net" -TypeDefinition @"
using System.Net;

public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    private int timeout = 60000;

    public MyWebClient(int timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    public int Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return timeout;
        }
        set
        {
            timeout = value;
        }
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(System.Uri webUrl)
    {
        WebRequest retVal = base.GetWebRequest(webUrl);
        retVal.Timeout = this.timeout;
        return retVal;
    }
}
"@
#endregion
#----> Improvement ends here

$urls= @("http://cardinals.local")

New-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "SharePoint Warmup Script" -    
ErrorAction      SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

$timeout = 60000 #=60 seconds               #<--- Improvement!

$urls | % {
$url = $_
try {
    $wc = New-Object MyWebClient($timeout)        #<--- Improvement!
    $wc.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
    $ret = $wc.DownloadString($url)
    if( $ret.Length -gt 0 ) {
        $s = "Last run successful for url ""$($url)"": $([DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy.dd.MM HH:mm:ss'))" 
        $filename=((Split-Path ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path))+"lastrunlog.txt")
        if( Test-Path $filename -PathType Leaf ) {
            $c = Get-Content $filename
            $cl = $c -split '`n'
            $s = ((@($s) + $cl) | select -First 200)
        }
        Out-File -InputObject ($s -join "`r`n") -FilePath $filename
    }
} catch {
      Write-EventLog -Source "SharePoint Warmup Script"  -Category 0 -ComputerName "." -EntryType Error -LogName "Application" `
        -Message "SharePoint Warmup failed for url ""$($url)""." -EventId 1001

    $s = "Last run failed for url ""$($url)"": $([DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy.dd.MM HH:mm:ss')) : $($_.Exception.Message)" 
    $filename=((Split-Path ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path))+"lastrunlog.txt")
    if( Test-Path $filename -PathType Leaf ) {
      $c = Get-Content $filename
      $cl = $c -split '`n'
      $s = ((@($s) + $cl) | select -First 200)
    }
    Out-File -InputObject ($s -join "`r`n") -FilePath $filename
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `$filename` variable to some other location like `"c:\lastrunlog.txt"`. The log file will be generated with complete output.

Try the updated script below:

```
#<---- Improvement starts here
#region MyWebClient
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies "System.Net" -TypeDefinition @"
using System.Net;

public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    private int timeout = 60000;

    public MyWebClient(int timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    public int Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return timeout;
        }
        set
        {
            timeout = value;
        }
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(System.Uri webUrl)
    {
        WebRequest retVal = base.GetWebRequest(webUrl);
        retVal.Timeout = this.timeout;
        return retVal;
    }
}
"@
#endregion
#----> Improvement ends here

$urls= @("http://cardinals.local")
$filename="c:\lastrunlog.txt"
New-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "SharePoint Warmup Script" -    
ErrorAction      SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

$timeout = 60000 #=60 seconds               #<--- Improvement!

$urls | % {
$url = $_
try {
    $wc = New-Object MyWebClient($timeout)        #<--- Improvement!
    $wc.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
    $ret = $wc.DownloadString($url)
    if( $ret.Length -gt 0 ) {
        $s = "Last run successful for url ""$($url)"": $([DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy.dd.MM HH:mm:ss'))" 
        if( Test-Path $filename -PathType Leaf ) {
            $c = Get-Content $filename
            $cl = $c -split '`n'
            $s = ((@($s) + $cl) | select -First 200)
        }
        Out-File -InputObject ($s -join "`r`n") -FilePath $filename
    }
} catch {
      Write-EventLog -Source "SharePoint Warmup Script"  -Category 0 -ComputerName "." -EntryType Error -LogName "Application" `
        -Message "SharePoint Warmup failed for url ""$($url)""." -EventId 1001

    $s = "Last run failed for url ""$($url)"": $([DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy.dd.MM HH:mm:ss')) : $($_.Exception.Message)" 
    if( Test-Path $filename -PathType Leaf ) {
      $c = Get-Content $filename
      $cl = $c -split '`n'
      $s = ((@($s) + $cl) | select -First 200)
    }
    Out-File -InputObject ($s -join "`r`n") -FilePath $filename
}
}
```

Comment: Tested and verified!

Comment: the script works great! I have created a job in Task Scheduler, but when I run the job the log file is not updating. The command I'm running is C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -command sp2010warmup.ps1

Comment: I found a solution, I created a batch file, and added powershell -command "& 'E:\Tools\Scripts\sp2010warmup.ps1'", then I configured the Task Scheduler to execute the batch file. Everything is working now. Thanks, Jason